# Edge Connectedness Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

By definition a graph is $e$-edge-connected if however we remove $e-1$ edge the graph remains connected. Example, we have 2 disjoint complete graph on 100 vertices, $K^1_{100}$ and $K^2_{100}$. We then add 5 edges between $K^1_{100}$ and $K^2_{100}$, each edge to a different vertex in both components. Now the graph is $5$-edge-connected.

I understand that by definition, if we remove 2 random edges, the graph becomes $3$-edge-connected, since if we remove 3 more edges the graph MAY be disconnected. However, aren't there a lot of cases that the graph also remains $5/4$-edge-connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said :

> I understand that by definition, if we remove 2 random edges, the graph becomes 3-edge-connected

**No**. The definition of being 5-edge-connected **does not** imply that you can remove any 2 edges and you will get a 3-edge-connected graph.

Being 5-edges-connected means there is no set of 4 edges disconnecting the graph. If it is not 6-edge-connected then there is one (at least one, but perhaps unique) set of 5 edges, such that if you remove precisely these one, your graphs is disconnected. Such a set of edges is called a 5-edge-cut.

From a 5-edge-connected graph:

- If you remove an edge in a 5-edge-cut, then you get a 4-edge-connected graph
- If you remove any other edge, your graph is still 5-edge-connected.

Therefore in your case, if you remove two **random** edges, your graph will probably not be 3-edge-connected. It will still be 5-edge-connected, or maybe 4-.

In your case the unique 5-edge cut is the set of the 5 edges you have added. If your remove 2 random edges outside of this set, the graph will still be 5-edge -connected. If one was inside this set, you get a 4-edge-connected, and if both were in the set you get a 3-edge-connected graph.

**EDIT**
What you teacher might have said therefore is that from a 5-edge-connected graph, if you remove any 2 edges, then you get a graph which is **at least** a 3-edge-connected graphs.

This is true because any $e$-edge-connected graph is also $e'$-edge-connected for any $e'\leq e$.

Comment: This is what I understood too, but I had this exact question on my exam, and the correct answer is $3$-edge-connected. I think, this implies that being $5$-edge-connected means that removing any 4 edges, the graph would still be connected. Thus if we remove only 2, we need to remove AT LEAST 3 more edges for it to be disconnected. This is the definition of '$e$-edge-connectedness', straight from my teacher: 'a directed graph G is $e$-edge-connected if no matter how we delete $\leq$ $e$-1 edges, G is still connected'

Comment: I've edited my post, yes you get a graph that is at least 3-edge-connected. maybe 4, maybe 5, but at least 3-edge connected with certainty.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting graph could be $3$-, $4$-, or $5$-edge-connected.

The graph has $2\binom{100}2+5=4955$ edges. It becomes $3$-edge-connected if and only if you remove $2$ of the $5$ edges between $K_{100}^1$ and $K_{100}^2$. The probability of reducing the edge-connectivity to $3$ is only

$$\frac{\binom52}{\binom{4955}2}=\frac{5\cdot4}{4955\cdot4954}=\frac2{991\cdot2477}=\frac2{2454707}\approx 0.0000008$$

if the edges to be removed are selected at random with all pairs equally likely to be selected. The probability that you end up with a $4$-edge-connected graph is

$$\frac{5\cdot4950}{\binom{4955}2}=\frac{49500}{4955\cdot4954}=\frac{4950}{2454707}\approx 0.0020165\;,$$

and the probability that you still have a $5$-edge-connected graph is therefore

$$1-\frac{4952}{2454707}=\frac{2449755}{2454707}\approx 0.9979827\;.$$

Comment: What I meant was, why do we call the graph $3$-edge-connected now, since as your working states, most likely it will stay as a $5$-edge-connected, and should we come across this graph without knowing the original one, we would likely label it as a $5$-edge-connected graph.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes: I can’t speak for people actually working in that field, since I don’t, but I **wouldn’t** call it $3$-edge-connected, though I could certainly say that it’s **at least** $3$-edge-connected.